# mvc 5 and web api 2 Google login (email retrieving)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-web-api, google-api

I am working on a application in which MVC is used as client side(front-end) and Web API as Server side. Authentication and authorization everything is working fine as CORS enabled. I configured google login with client id and client secrete, google login is working fine but i am unable to retrieve the email as it is returning null always. I can retrieve email when i use everything like client side and server side in Web Api.

Can anyone help me through this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that's returning null?

Comment: Hi david, thanks for looking into my post Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() is null always so i customized it by using claims and ExternalLoginInfo(), by using this i am getting username and provider but not email, Email is always null, can you help me to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it's might help you so much.

[Code! MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)